# Multiple entries using SQL Update Query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

Would this SQL query work for an SQL database?

```
UPDATE tableName SET colName1='value' WHERE colName2='Id_1' OR colName2='Id_2'
```

Basically, can I update the same column for multiple entries by checking against another column twice?
For example(as shown above), set colName1 to a value for 2 seperate entries which are identified by two different IDs

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: Yes, that should work, although `colName2 in ('Id_1', 'Id_2')` would more commonly be used.

Comment: @GordonLinoff:- Bingo!!! Thats what I answered ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that would work but you can make it more efficient like this:

```
UPDATE tableName SET colName1='value' WHERE colName2 in('Id_1','Id_2')
```